# AWS Lambda function signal success or failure of the execution

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I created a aws lambda function and trying to integrate it with AWS Connect.
The lambda function resets the directory password. AWS Connect triggers the lambda function, the function reset the password and signal AWS Connect success or failed. How do I include signal in the code?

```
import logging
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = reset_user_password()
    return event
    
def reset_user_password():    
    response = client.reset_user_password(
    DirectoryId='d-xxxxxxxxxx',
    UserName='username',
    NewPassword='Password'
)
```

Comment: In the reset function, you aren't returning `response`.

Comment: How do I fix that? Sorry I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean by signal, but you can add visibility into the response or error message with something like this for your reset function:

```
def reset_user_password():    
    try:
        response = client.reset_user_password(
            DirectoryId='d-xxxxxxxxxx',
            UserName='username',
            NewPassword='Password'
        )
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response = str(e)
    return response
```

Also, you are calling the reset function in the lambda handler before it is defined, which will throw an error. You need to update the code like this:

```
import logging
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ds')

def reset_user_password():    
    try:
        response = client.reset_user_password(
            DirectoryId='d-xxxxxxxxxx',
            UserName='username',
            NewPassword='Password'
        )
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        response = str(e)
    return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = reset_user_password()
    return response
```

Comment: Ok, it appears that the 'def lambda_handler(event, context):' needs to return simple json format/flat object. eg, return {"hello":"world"}. In this case, how do I return simple json format in my code?

Comment: Use the json module... https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html